# open-classifieds : how create my own controller,model ,and view

Tags: php

I have install open source open-classifieds script. I want modified my landing page without theme look. So I required to create new controller or view.

Any one have idea please share with me.
I have search documentation but not found as my acceptations and support available only for paid version.

link of script [click here to see script site](http://open-classifieds.com)
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Please use https://forums.open-classifieds.com/

Those are the FREE forums ;)